# UK visa for my green card Filipino wife, do we have to have all accommodations paid for and planned in advance

Tags: visas, filipino-citizens

We are wanting to travel to UK, specifically Scotland. We only plan to get a hotel for 3 days in Edinburgh and then travel around for 3 weeks and get hotel accommodations as we go without a firm travel structure.

In trying to get a UK visa for my green card Filipino wife, do we have to have all accommodations paid for and planned out in advance? If so that would kill the trip for us.

Thank you so much for trying to help this old man.

Comment: As the linked question shows, the UK guidance for visa applicants **explicitly recommends against** paying for travel or accommodation before you know you have a visa.

Comment: I searched and was not able to find this. My primary question has to do with if we had to have a "firm travel structure" In any case I appreciate your help

Comment: x @Migo, if you edit the question to make that clearer, we can reopen it and see if it attracts answers.

Comment: Thank you Henning. I think I got the message and the answer I needed.

Comment: You would have a "firm travel structure" if you find out when you want to go, what flights you want to take, what places you want to visit, what hotels you want to use - without actually spending money yet. In the end, the UK government doesn't want you to waste money without need.